# How to typedef a function according to tslint with "() => void"?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, tslint

I have a function that needs to be typed:

```
const checkIfTagNeedsToBeCounted = (listOfTags: string[]): boolean => {
  const tagsToExcludeFromCounting: string[] = [
    "DoNotCount",
  ];

  const excludedTagFound: boolean = listOfTags.some(
    (singleTag) => tagsToExcludeFromCounting.includes(singleTag),
  );

  return !excludedTagFound;
};
```

When doing

```
const checkIfTagNeedsToBeCounted: Function = ...
```

tslint is mocking:

Don't use 'Function' as a type. Avoid using the `Function` type. Prefer a specific function type, like `() => void`. (ban-types)

So far I've been ignoring the problem with

```
// tslint:disable-next-line: ban-types
const checkIfTagNeedsToBeCounted: Function = (listOfTags: string[]): boolean => {
```

but I'm eager to know what the proper way of typedefing a function is according to tslint?

Comment: what I normally do is typing it as you are typing it in the function signature:
`(args: ArgsType) => ReturnType`

Comment: Why do you type it explicitly after all? Why not let TS infer the type?

Comment: Because sometimes you get the types wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Function` is indeed not precise enough.

As typescript tell you, you need to define precisely the prototype of the function you want to use.

You will gain auto-completion and error detection (wrong parameter ...etc).

You have two ways to handle that, either you let typescript to infer the type of the function.

Either you define yourself the type of the function.

**NOTE**: Choose the second option if typescript cannot infer properly (it's the case when you use `any` a lot), or If you want to reuse the type.

---

In your case :

```
const checkIfTagNeedsToBeCounted: (listOfTags:string[]) => boolean = (listOfTags: string[]): boolean => {
   // ...
};
```

---

If you want to reuse the function type :

```
type MyFunction = (listOfTags: string[]) => boolean;

const checkIfTagNeedsToBeCounted: MyFunction = (listOfTags: string[]): boolean => {
   // ...
};
```